# Command "sudo service tomcat start" shows FAIL but everything is working

Tags: tomcat, service, startup, failover

I'm wondering why I obtain a [FAIL] when I execute "sudo service tomcat start" on my aws ubuntu server, even if everything just goes on fine, tomcat starts and deploy applications.

Did it ever happened to you? I should fix this because I have some scripts that are failing because of that [FAIL]. I am using Tomcat7.

Thanks.

EDIT 20140213: I found that this is happening because of two lines added to catalina.sh, these two line are two exports to set some environment variables:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

These two lines are working pretty well in setting those variables, the only issue is that [fail] result. If I remove them result is [ok] but I get memory problems.

Does anyone have some hints to where to put those export in a way that catalina.sh get an [ok] result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put those options in a setenv.sh file.

Actually this helped me:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/538831/Tomcat/place-put-JAVA-OPTS-setting